# Different behavior on mobile and desktop for menu using transform and flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, transform

I try to have a menu hidden on the right of my screen (with a transform), and it comes back on the screen when the icon is hovered.
It works perfectly fine on desktop (chromium and firefox), but acts weirdly on mobile (chrome and firefox).

Here it how it appears when it's supposed to be hidden on mobile.

[image: mobile-hidden]

I tried this code in a new project with this and nothing more, and it keeps having a weird behavior on mobile and on mobile emulation with firefox dev tools. Can't manage to have it using snippet tho.

[live version running here](https://optimistic-dijkstra-d4dfc1.netlify.app/). Opening it on mobile or with the dev tools and mobile emulation makes it weird. You can also see the difference between desktop and mobile.

UPDATE: if I hide the menu on the left or top sides, it remains hidden without any zoom out or scroll issue. But as soon as I hide it on the right or bottom sides, I have the zoom out / scrolling issue on mobiles.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  background: #424242;
  transform: translate(200%, 0);
  transition: transform .5s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.icon { 
  display: block;
  height: 3rem; 
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  path { fill: #000; }
  z-index: 99;
}

.icon:hover ~ .menu {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div>
        <nav>
          <svg class='icon' viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 10H14V8H0V10ZM0 0V2H14V0H0ZM0 6H14V4H0V6Z" fill="black"/>
          </svg>

          <ul class="menu">
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      <main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</main>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Many thanks!
Matthieu

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As the question sits, your issue cannot be replicated.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. You might have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: As I couldn't manage to make it happen on here, I hosted it the code sample on Netlify. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but yet I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. So I managed to fix it by adding `position: fixed;` to the parent of my menu. I'm not sure if I fixed it or if it's sort of a cheat code, but yet it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your netlify examples is too basic, it lacks even basic styling for body, main and nav.
Also, in that sample example, we find, when inspecting the svg's `.icon` class:

[image]

As for the original issue, it is not working perfectly for me on desktop if I go by your statement of 'pressing a button'. there's only a hover interaction:

[image]

It seems like you either did not describe your problem adequately, or your sample code does not really look like your real thing.

Comment: Yes, this is just a really basic example. The full app is a full Nextjs app, so I just managed to grab the least possible things to make the issue happen again. Regarding the "press the button", I indeed set it as just a hover in the Netlify app, I should've mention that.